# Why can't I access Child objects in my BindingSource in the Advanced Binding Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

I have the following classes;

```
public class Booking
{
    public int BookingId {get;set;}
    public bool Cancelled {get;set;}
    public BookingSummary BookingSummary {get;set;}
}

public class BookingSummary
{
   public string Comments {get;set;}
   public decimal TotalRate {get;set;}
}
```

In my windows application, I have added a BindingSource to my form, and I'm trying to map Booking.BookingSummary.TotalRate property to a text box.  But as you can see in the dialog box below, the BookingSummary isn't expandable, so I can't pick the child property TotalRate.

[image]

Can anyone help and advise how I can overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

supposing your textbox is named textbox1 and your bindingsource is bindingsource1:

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "BookingSummary.TotalRate");
```

Comment: Am I not able to do this in the designer ?

Comment: from the properties window from formatting and advanced i dont think so.